# How to call python scripts into visual studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am required to call python scripts into as my project is a webcam project. I needed to call a normalization python script and edit it.

Comment: What is the calling language? If it's visual studio, is it C#?

Comment: Hi the calling language is c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF this is still a problem for you, I'd recommend calling the python script as a command line call, [as shown in this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands). You can save the output of the python script as a file and then read that file in to your C# program.

Keep in mind that this is generally not advisable, and there are better ways to go about this in a production system. This ranges from communicating over ports on the local network to using more advanced interprocess communication techniques; these vary from language to language. Still other applications use databases for local communication between processes.

Comment: Hi, i think this might just work out but how do i browse my python script? for the part that i do not how these 2 works: strCmdText and startInfo.Arguments

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: Oh. Add them wherever you need the data from the script, and then wait for the python script to finish executing. Is it not possible to emulate the functionality in c#? That would be easiest. Inter process communication is very hard.

Comment: Hi, i am able to open the cmd prompt but how do i call my python script? i wanted to make it so that when i use this program it automatically helps to open the cmd prompt and call the python scripts automatically but not manually calling the script.